# Nutch selenium firefox issue: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, web-crawler, nutch

I'm trying to set up a headless crawler using Nutch Selenium and Firefox. 
I do have xvfb running and a display set. If I use the conf/nutch-site.xml with changes only to use protocol-selenium and if the seed list has more than 1 url, the fetch errors out saying either one of the following error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms.

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Failed to connect to binary FirefoxBinary(/usr/bin/firefox) on port 7055

java.lang.RuntimeException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.

firefox selenium nutch GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion `sys_page_size == 0' failed
```

If however there is only 1 url in the seed list, the fetcher is successful.

Now, if I change in conf/nutch-site.xml - fetcher.threads.per.queue to 1, and there are multiple urls in the seed list, the fetcher runs for a couple of them, but fails with any of the above errors for some.

The behaviour seems to be random, though I'm pretty sure there is something I'm not seeing right.

I'm on Amazon AMI Linux, Nutch 1.13, which has Selenium 2.48.2 and Firefox 31.4.0 
Tried with FF (40.0.0, 35.0 but still same situation)

I was able to see the questions asked all over, but did not find a reliable answer. I'd appreciate any help or suggestion.

Thanks!

Comment: hi @arunondeck did you ever solve this issue? I have the same issue with nutch 1.15 Selenium 2.48.2 and Firefox 57 and 68?